# EmguCV 64-bit build runtime error

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I am running into issues building an existing 32-bit EmguCV (**Version 2.3**) into 64-bit using .net 4.0 and VS2010 on a W7/x64 OS. I have purchased a commercial license, if that matters and downloaded from the links provided in the receipt.

The error is

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
 Message=The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.
 Source=Emgu.CV
 TypeName=Emgu.CV.CvInvoke
```

I followed the instructions provided in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EMGU_Image_Processing.aspx?display=PrintAll). In fact I used the samples projects in the article and they build fine with V2.2, but when I replace with V2.3 binaries (both emgu and opencv), run into the error.

Has anyone successfully built an Emgu (**Version 2.3.x**) x64 project? Please provide some guidance.

Comment: and Yes I have added the *correct* binaries from opencv into my debug folder. So it cannot be a simple missing dll error.

Comment: Hi Mikos, I found it quite funny to find that the article was one I wrote. I'll have a look into the problem now and get back to you. Cheers

Comment: @Chris, thanks. I followed your instructions to the letter - it was indeed very helpful. Sincerely appreciate your help and support.

Comment: Hi, well I've compiled the projects using EMGU 2.3.0 x64 and everything works fine. The error you mention could be down to to not targeting the correct platform. Does the InnerException read {"An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)"} if so then this is the problem. If not could you post it so I can try and recreate the problem. Cheers

Comment: "convertion from Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgra, System.Byte> to Image<Emgu.CV.Structure.Bgr, System.Byte> is not supported by OpenCV"

Comment: The error I face is the TypeInitializationException followed by the above convertion (sic) error. I am not sure what the problem is. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is there a sample project you can share with emgu 2.3 (x64) you can share?

Comment: Ok, so it's when you converting between image types. Chance are your trying to convert more than one data type at a time EMGU does not like this for some reason. So if I wanted to convert from <Bgr, Byte> to <Bgra, Double> I would have to do the following  Image<Bgra, Double> My_double_image = my_BGR_BYTE_Image.Convert<Bgra, Byte>().Convert<Bgra, Double>();   I did manage to reproduce a similar error by converting to a <Bgr,Double> then to a <Bgra,Double> so I now have to convert the image depth before the data type. If this doesn't help post the code that produces the error Cheers

Comment: I will upload the new 2.3.0 versions to code project as soon as I get chance at work

Comment: The codebase is available here: https://www.yousendit.com/download/T2dmNnFJYXk1R05WeHNUQw

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4562/discussion-between-mikos-and-chris)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of this error (should anyone else run into the same problem) is that the program cannot access opencv_imgproc231.dll or opencv_core231.dll even though they are present in the output "bin" directory.

There are two solutions:

1. Add them to the project and set their properties to `copy always` as they are EMGU's two key files.
2. If step 1 doesn't work, replace the current key files in the bin folder with new copies.

If both methods fail then there may be a problem with the build, so download a new copy of EMGU from Sourceforge and try again.  The error will later be incorporated within an technical article in order to provide a clearer explanation of how to solve it.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Hello @Chris. I tried adding those two refernces to my project, but somehow I wasn't allowed to add it. It said `Reference could not added reason being it is not accessible or it is not a valid assembly/COM component` . Please help!

Comment: Hi the files mentioned are the unmanaged opencv code what EMGU wraps effectively they aren't .NET components and have to be added to the output directory or as existing files within your project. See my article at codeproject and it will walk you through it http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/EMGU_Image_Processing.aspx Cheers

Answer (score 1):

No need to add them to the project; VS will not let you. Simply open `FaceRecognizer.cs`
at `public static partial class CvInvoke` and change:

```
[DllImport(CvInvoke.EXTERN_LIBRARY, CallingConvention = CvInvoke.CvCallingConvention)]
```

to:

```
[DllImport(Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.EXTERN_LIBRARY, CallingConvention = Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.CvCallingConvention)]
```

Ensure you change all of them.

Answer (score 1):

First test this way: open a sample project from emgu cv installaiton directory and run it. for example, open hello world example and try to run it. if sample projects run with out problem then the installation is correct.

For emgu cv sample projects, value of **Output Path** option in **Build** settings of the **project** is set to **'..\..\
bin'**. To fix your project problem, open the project in visual studio and set value of **Output Path** option to **'C:\Emgu\emgucv 2.9\bin'**. Try to run the project. It must run with success.

Now, set back the value of Output Path option to **bin\Debug\**. Then, add all DLL files in the **'C:\Emgu\emgucv 2.9\bin'** folder to your project using ADD -> Existing Item menu. similarly, add all DLL files in the **'C:\Emgu\emgucv 2.9\bin\x64'** folder to your project using ADD -> Existing Item menu. Now, go to properties window and set **Copy to Output Directory** option of all dll files to **Copy Always**. Finally, in the Configuration Manager window, create a new configuration for **x64** platform.

Good Luck